# How to return just JSON response from Laravel 4 REST API?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Laravel RESTful API setup that needs to return data in JSON format to an app on one of my subdomains ( and thus not within the Laravel app itself ).

In the REST I am returning like:

```
return \Response::json(array(
    "status"  => "success",
    "type"    => "client",
    "message" => "Nothing to see here!"
));
```

In my Class on the subdomain app I am simply trying to return this response to a view print the output for testing.

I would hope that I just get back JSON, but when I do a simple:

```
echo $resp;
```

I get nothing

If I do a:

```
print_r( $resp );
```

or

```
json_decode( $resp );
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.35
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Sat, 06 Dec 2014 04:18:15 GMT
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ik5DdDFGK2tJQ3ZCVkJPQnRtZHRaU2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT2tXSTJWYzRKUXZncG9NOFZBYkhOUTZRaUg1c3NmUXlHTjF5bzYyaTZRYUY4S3VBMEdwdjdwdXNUNHkwblppV1I5YUFsY2dodGNyRHh5SmZYeGFjcWc9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijc0Mzg3MGNlNTBiYTEyNTE3MzNhZDVjNjUzNzMwNzk0ZTMwN2MwYmFiNDIyMGE0N2MyNTQxMDNlMDdiOGFmOTQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 06-Dec-2014 06:18:15 GMT; path=/; httponly

{"status":"success","type":"client","message":"Nothing to see here!"}
```

I don't want all of that headers stuff in my response like that. Or I am receiving and trying to parse it incorrectly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a dumb mistake not with the REST API, but with the cURL call to the API.

If this ever happens to you just check and make sure you do not have:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

That will output the headers with the response and mess up your day. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

My return is like this:

```
return Response::json(array($data));
```

Just store array to a variable and call that variable on to the response.